# Expo Notification - How to update a specific notification content?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm starting a little project with Expo Notifications API and I'd like to update the scheduled notification content (body content). Looking up the official DOC, I couldn't find anything about how to do that.

For instance, I can schedule a notification by typing:

```
const id = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
  content: {
     title: 'Notification',
     body: 'Notification body',
     subtitle: 'Order progress'
  }
});
```

By means of the notification identifier `id`, I'd like in some way to update this specific notification content:

```
// Example
Notifications.updateNotificationAsync(id, { 
 content: {
    title: 'Stocks notification',
    body: 'Updated body',
    subtitle: 'Updated order progress'
 }
});
```

Would it be possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not cancel and schedule a new one?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for that. You can only cancel the existing notification and schedule a new one with updated data.