# Update notification content, react-native expo-notification

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, expo

Trying to implement notification timer (kinda like default IOS timer -> its working in both app and notification mode) For that seems like i need to be able to update notification content. Is it even possible while using expo-notification?

Found this quesion - no answer though:
[Expo Notification - How to update a specific notification content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75527086/expo-notification-how-to-update-a-specific-notification-content)
Also nice package here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-custom-timer-notification
But it's only for android :(